# No matching distribution found for python3-requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, windows-10

Taking a course: [Using Python to Interact with the Operating System](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-operating-system/home/info). I have very poor vision, so I am trying to install some python stuff on windows 10 (please see below) so I can edit and run some of the files at home.

How can I find and install the python3-requests?

```
PS D:\ray\goapps\code4> C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310/Scripts/pip3.exe install python3-requests
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-requests (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python3-requests

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2.1 -> 22.3
[notice] To update, run: C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
PS D:\ray\goapps\code4>
```

Comment: Does `pip install requests` work for you?

Comment: haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go into command line by typing cmd in the search bar and type in exactly `pip install requests` and that should work from there you can just use import requests at the top of your python file and use the library.